# Android WebView not running HLS Streaming

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in JQuery Mobile. I am using HLS.js for live streaming. I have the following code for running streams.

```
    <video id="video" controls width="100%"></video>
<script>
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var hls = new Hls();
  // bind them together
  hls.attachMedia(video);
  // MEDIA_ATTACHED event is fired by hls object once MediaSource is ready
  hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
        console.log("video and hls.js are now bound together !");
         hls.loadSource("http://mystream.m3u8");
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
      console.log("manifest loaded, found " + data.levels.length + " quality    level");
      video.play();
    });
  });
}
```

But on my local system when I run the code through the localhost the stream works fine. But without the localhost it gives following error on console :

> Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/9421fa05-21d8-4d17-a9f3-64d83a56acbe

I am loading the html files in the webview using the following code

```
     webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvPortal);

    WebSettings mWebSettings = webView.getSettings();

    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); 
    mWebSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/views/index.html");
```

I can't run the app on localhost from the android device , kindly tell me how can I solve this issue.